# Giving more memory to mex programs in Matlab

Tags: c, matlab, mex

My C mex-compiled files are running out of memory (more specifically, my calls to `mxMalloc` sometimes return `NULL`). From a quick calculation I estimate that my files ask `mxMalloc` for about 500 MB of memory in total (maybe as much as 1 GB), and I run my files on a 64 bit Linux machine with 16 GB of memory running Matlab almost exclusively. Yet, `mxMalloc` returns `NULL` quite often.

I guess that that there are several reasons why this could happen (memory fragmentation, etc.), but in any case, 500 MB do not seem to be that much to ask from a 16-GB-memory machine.

I presume that my calls to `mxMalloc` request memory from Matlab's heap, but am not 100% sure about it ( `mxMalloc` requests are handled by Matlab after all, and not directly by the OS). So is there a way of increasing my mex file's "heap" size?

Thanks

Comment: You run out of memory during a single execution of mex function, or in some point after many executions of the same file (i.e. in a loop)? The reason I ask is that I used to have memory problems after executing a mex file many times (in a loop). I found that the problem was in the way I returned results from mex to matlab.

Comment: @Marcin, it usually happens after a few (<10) calls to mex files. I'll look more carefully into the way I return results from mex to Matlab in case there is something wrong I am doing, but is there anything I should be aware of (e.g. general bad vs good practice)? If I `mxFree` my data before returning, shouldn't that put the heap back into (pretty much) its original fragmentation state?

Comment: Have a look here (http://goo.gl/sYB3R). Maybe this post will give you some clues what may be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `malloc` (not `mxMalloc`) but the memory must be managed manually (e.g. You *must* call `free`; it's not optional like `mxFree` is). You could also try compiling using c++ and boost's shared/scoped pointers. Your `mexFunction` signature will need `extern "C"` prepended to it.

One reason you may be running out of memory is that your arrays are too long.`mxArray` must be contiguous data. So `mxMalloc`ing them and the `mxFree`ing them could fragment your memory space. While std::vector must be contiguous too, std::list doesn't have to be.

Something like the original STL's `rope` class could be a good implementation too.